# .findFragmentById doesn't get id from context.

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to set up a maps_Activity but when I try the code to cast the Id of the fragment it doesn't find it.

Here is the code of the java file:

```
    public class map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener{
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
           SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
   getSupportFragmentManager()
                   .findFragmentById(map);
           mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

And here is the code for the xml file:

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="com.synergy.beberapp_prototype_02.map" />
```

The **map** fragment is properly identify in the xml file but the java file doesn't seems to find it.

Thanks

Comment: The method `findFragmentById` takes an integer value. What is the value of `map`? Try to get the integer id corresponding to the id in your xml with `R`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
   .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

Comment: Worked like a charm, funny thing thoug, because I have a different project where it didn't need it. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I dont know how you managed to get it work without it tho. Can you please accept the answer ? Thanks =)